# Vertical scroll rendering issue in Flexbox in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I want to contain a flex item within the parent so that it does not spill outside of the parent. Only the flex item should have a scrollbar (if necessary).

My styling works fine within Chrome and IE11, but not Firefox. I suspect there is a difference in interpretation of the `flex-basis` style set on `#wrapper`, but I cannot figure out why Firefox renders this differently.

Here's the desired rendering as seen in Chrome:

[image: Chrome rendering screenshot]

And here's what happens in Firefox:

[image: Firefox rendering screenshot]

I could apply a "duct tape" fix by adding `#left { height: calc(100vh - 50px); }`, but I'd prefer to identify the actual inconsistency if possible.

```css
body, html, h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
}
#main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 0%;
}
#left {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 30%;
}
.box {
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the flexbox specification's [implied minimum sizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276).

<s>This is a [**Firefox bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520).</s>

Adding `min-width: 0; min-height: 0` to `#wrapper` seems to  do the trick:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 2;
    flex-basis: 0%;
    min-height: 0; /* NEW */
    min-width: 0; /* NEW */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjdb2m9m/)

---

Original Answer Below

<s>*Currently you have `overflow-y: scroll` applied to `#left`.*</s>

If you also apply `overflow-y: scroll` to `#wrapper`, the vertical scroll launches in Firefox.

As to why Firefox interprets the code differently than Chrome I can't say. The rendering engines have their differences. I recently addressed another [flexbox interpretation issue between IE11 and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885534/how-to-make-flex-end-work-in-ie11):

More information:

- [Bug 1043520 - (minsizeauto-fallout) Tracking bug for web content breaking due to new "min-width:auto" / "min-height:auto" behavior on flex items](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520)
- [Bug 570036 - Flexible box does not allow overflow scrolling of children elements without extra markup](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570036)
- DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/seqgz8qv/ (scroll works in FF)
- [Scroll not working with CSS3 flex box in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328897/scroll-not-working-with-css3-flex-box-in-firefox)
- [Flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app using NEWER flexbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api)
- [Scrolling a flexbox with overflowing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515042/scrolling-a-flexbox-with-overflowing-content)