# Why is HTML holy grail with flex works on Chrome but not on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

The code: http://plnkr.co/edit/swHKE2?p=preview. See snippet below as well.

The code is an example of the [Holy grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)).

On Chrome (v46.0.2490.80 m) it works perfectly - has header, footer, sides and only content is scrollable without hiding the frame.

On FF (v42.0), the vertical scroll is on everything, ignoring the flex directive.

**Any idea how to fix the styling to have the right behavior on FF?** Thanks.

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Holy Grail</title>
  </head>
  <body style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
    <div>HEADER<br/>------------
    </div>
    <!-- No need for 'flex-direction: row' because it's the default value -->
    <div style="display: flex; flex: 1">
      <div>NAV|</div>
      <div style="flex: 1; overflow: auto">
        CONTENT - START<br/>
        <script>
        for (var i=0 ; i<1000 ; ++i) {
          document.write(" Very long content!");
        }
        </script>
        <br/>CONTENT - END
      </div>
      <div>|SIDE</div>
    </div>
    <div>------------<br/>FOOTER</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the flexbox specification's [implied minimum sizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276).

<s>I believe this is a [**Firefox bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520).</s>

Adding `min-width: 0; min-height: 0` to the first nested flex container seems to  do the trick:

```
<body style="display: flex; height: 100%; flex-direction: column">
  <div>HEADER<br/>------------
  </div>
  <!-- No need for 'flex-direction: row' because it's the default value -->
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 1; min-width: 0; min-height: 0;"> <!-- ADJUSTEMENT -->
    <div>NAV|</div>
          ...
          ...
          ...
          ...
```

More information:

- [Vertical scroll rendering issue in Flexbox in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911324/3597276)
- [Bug 1043520 - (minsizeauto-fallout) Tracking bug for web content breaking due to new "min-width:auto" / "min-height:auto" behavior on flex items](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1043520)
- [Bug 570036 - Flexible box does not allow overflow scrolling of children elements without extra markup](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570036)