# How to fit flexbox containers to page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After much effort I have put together a flexbox layout intended to be a layout for a web application. There's a few outcomes I'm having trouble achieving - here are my goals:

- the footer sticky to the bottom even as the page is resized
- the header sticky to the top os the page is resized
- the middle section of three columns to adjust in height as the browser is resized
- the right hand column to stretch to the edge of the
  page

These pictures show that for some reason the page is taller than the viewing window of the browser.

[image]
[image]

Here's the page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>flexbox layout test</title>
<style>
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
align-items: center;
}

.containerrow1 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
background-color: yellow;
}

.containerrow2 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.outercontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
background-color: black;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
}


.section-nav {
  order: -1;
background-color: blue;
}

.section-nav, .section-content, .section-ads {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 2em;
}

</style>

  </head>
<body class='section'>


  <div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="containerrow1">
<div class="topbar">
  Blah
</div>
</div>

  <div class="containerrow2">

<main class="section-content">
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section <br/>content section
</main>
    <nav class="section-nav">
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
nav section <br/> nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>nav section <br/>
</nav>
    <aside class="section-ads">
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
ads section <br/> ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>ads section <br/>
</aside>

  </div>

  <div class="containerrow1">
<div class="topbar">
  footer
</div>
</div>

  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I don't know who to award the correct answer to.  Seems to me possibly everyone contributed and shared some knowledge. Can anyone suggest an appropriate outcome?

Comment: From [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work): *The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.*

Answer (score 1):

Add these styles:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;        /* allow content to take entire screen space */
}

.outercontainer {
  height: 100%;     /* make this the height of the screen, preventing overflow */
}

.section-ads {
  flex: 1;          /* make this take the rest of the right space */
}
```

In my Snippet, I renamed `.section-ads` to `.section-ads1`, because Chrome is hiding it, possibly due to an ad-blocker(?).

Also, remove this style:

```
.containerrow1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.containerrow1 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.containerrow2 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}
.outercontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 100vh;
}
.section-nav {
  order: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}
.section-nav,
.section-content,
.section-ads1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 2em;
}

.section-ads1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class='section'>
  <div class="outercontainer">
    <div class="containerrow1">
      <div class="topbar">
        Blah
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="containerrow2">
      <main class="section-content">
        content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
        <br/>content section
      </main>
      <nav class="section-nav">
        nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>nav section
        <br/>
      </nav>
      <aside class="section-ads1">
        ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>ads section
        <br/>
      </aside>

    </div>

    <div class="containerrow1">
      <div class="topbar">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks BUT and I'm sorry if I wasn't clear about this - I want to maintain the existing functionality where each of the columns has a scroll bar, with the column content scrollable.  The example code does this.

Comment: Hmm, my solution has three scrollbars in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.  Is that what you're using?

Comment: OSX Firefox 42 - the footer is not sticky so the page is taller than the browser viewing area.

Comment: Looks like @Michael_B has the answer for Firefox:  Add these styles to `.containerrow2`:  `min-height: 0; min-width: 0; `.

Comment: On Opera 31 OSX  the footer is sticky.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a bit. The `.section` class was never applied since you did `class="section-content"` but then the former never applies. Change this to: `class="section content"` and instead of `.section-content`you can style this using `.section` and `.section.content`.

Also, setting `vh: 100` on the section layer won't help since "vh" means viewport height, but not the height of the actual content.

Lastly I think you need an additional scroll layer to style the backgrounds as you like. Here is some updated code that should work as you intended:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.topbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.containerrow1 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 2vh;
}
.containerrow2 {
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: pink;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.outercontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.section.nav {
  order: -1;
  background-color: blue;
}
.section.nav,
.section.content,
.section.ads {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<body class='section'>
  <div class="outercontainer">
    <div class="containerrow1">
      <div class="topbar">Blah</div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="containerrow2">
        <main class="section content">content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section
          <br/>content section</main>
        <nav class="section nav">nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>nav section
          <br/>
        </nav>
        <aside class="section ads">ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>ads section
          <br/>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerrow1">
      <div class="topbar">footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow thankyou awesome although please see the comment I made to the response by @RickHitchcock - I want to maintain the existing functionality that I have whereby each column has it's own scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

> There's a few outcomes I'm having trouble achieving - here are my
>   goals:
>
> - the footer sticky to the bottom even as the page is resized
> - the header sticky to the top os the page is resized
> - the middle section of three columns to adjust in height as the browser is resized
> - the right hand column to stretch to the edge of the page

So it seems like you've got much of it going. You just need to get the right-hand column to stretch and limit the entire layout to the size of the viewport.

Here are a few lines of code to make it all work.

1. Remove default `margin` from `body`.

   ```
   html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0; /* new */
   }
   ```

   *Explanation: [HTML default body margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127887/html-default-body-margin)*

---

2. Add a `height` to `.outercontainer`.

   ```
   .outercontainer {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: black;
       height: 100%; /* new */
   }
   ```

   *Explanation: [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)*

---

3. Patch a Firefox bug involving vertical scrollbars in flexbox

   ```
   .containerrow2 {
       margin: 15px;
       padding: 15px;
       display: flex;
       flex: 2;
       background-color: pink;
       height: 100vh;
       min-height: 0; /* new */
       min-width: 0; /* new */
   }
   ```

   *Explanation: [Vertical scroll rendering issue in Flexbox in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911324/3597276)*

---

4. Stretch the right-most column

   `.section-ads { flex: 1; }`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1wjtxbjo/3/)

Comment: Nice one although in the demo fiddle the right hand section does not stretch to the right hand side of the page.

Comment: I misunderstood your original request. I understand what you mean now. I've revised my answer and demo.